# Actualizar multiples registros en la BD, 1 vez por registro en Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, api, ruby

tengo un código que esta actualizando registros de usuarios en una BD, pero esta actualizando el registro de cada usuario la cantidad de veces que hay usuarios en la BD, ej. tengo 3 usuarios => medic1, medic2, medic4 en el SQL se puede ver que esta actualizándolos 3 veces cuando debería ser 1 vez por registro.

Lo que debería hacer mi código es extraer de la BD a los usuarios con el atributo anidado period_end_date y guardarlos en un hash, el cuál hará una consulta a la API de Openpay sobre el estado de la suscripción; en el response_hash recibo los datos de cada usuario y dependiendo del 'status' actualizo los valores en la base de datos con los resultados del response_hash, esto debería ser por usuario. No consigo ver que estoy haciendo mal, me pueden ayudar a lograrlo?

Aquí esta el código:

```
namespace :premium_users do
  desc 'Get the user id & data in a hash'
  task get_users: :environment do 
    users = Medic.includes(:payment_methods).where.not payment_methods: { period_end_date: nil }
    request_hash = {}

    users.each do |user|
      period_end_date = user.payment_methods.last.period_end_date

      if Date.today - period_end_date <= 172_800
        openpay_customer_id = user.payment_methods.last.openpay_customer_id
        openpay_subscription_id = user.payment_methods.last.openpay_subscription_id
        medic_id = user.payment_methods.last.medic_id
        user_hash = {}
        user_hash[medic_id] = [openpay_customer_id, openpay_subscription_id]
      else
        user_hash = {}
      end

      request_hash.merge!(user_hash) # If no users is empty => {}

      if request_hash.empty?
       puts 'No User to check!'
      else
        request_hash.each_value do |value|
          openpay_customer_id = value[0]
          openpay_subscription_id = value[1]

          @openpay = OpenpayApi.new(ENV['MERCHANT_ID_OPENPAY'], ENV['SECRET_KEY_OPENPAY'])
          @subscriptions = @openpay.create(:subscriptions)
          response_hash = @subscriptions.get(openpay_subscription_id, openpay_customer_id)

          @charge_date, @creation_date, @current_period_number, @period_end_date, @status, @trial_end_date = response_hash.values_at('charge_date', 'creation_date', 'current_period_number', 'period_end_date', 'status', 'trial_end_date')

          case @status
          when 'past_due'
            @premium = false
            @cancelled = Time.now
          when 'unpaid'
            @premium = false
            @cancelled = Time.now
          when 'cancelled'
            @premium = false
            @cancelled = Time.now
          else
            @premium = true
            @cancelled = nil
          end

        end

        @payment_method = PaymentMethod.update(
          premium: @premium,
          charge_date: @charge_date,
          creation_date: @creation_date,
          current_period_number: @current_period_number,
          period_end_date: @period_end_date,
          status: @status,
          trial_end_date: @trial_end_date,
          cancelled_on: @cancelled
        )

        puts "User #{user.email} update, Complete!"

      end
    end
  end
end
```

Mis modelos:

```
class Medic < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :payment_methods, dependent: :destroy
end

class PaymentMethod < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :medic, optional: true 
end
```

Resultado de rake premium_users:get_users:

SQL (0.5ms)  SELECT `medics`.`id` AS t0_r0, `medics`.`email` AS t0_r1,     `medics`.`encrypted_password` AS t0_r2, `medics`.`reset_password_token` AS t0_r3, `medics`.`reset_password_sent_at` AS t0_r4, `medics`.`remember_created_at` AS t0_r5, `medics`.`sign_in_count` AS t0_r6, `medics`.`current_sign_in_at` AS t0_r7, `medics`.`last_sign_in_at` AS t0_r8, `medics`.`current_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r9, `medics`.`last_sign_in_ip` AS t0_r10, `medics`.`created_at` AS t0_r11, `medics`.`updated_at` AS t0_r12, `medics`.`full_name` AS t0_r13, `medics`.`clinic_name` AS t0_r14, `medics`.`clinic_address` AS t0_r15, `medics`.`medic_specialty` AS t0_r16, `medics`.`contact_phone` AS t0_r17, `medics`.`emergency_contact_phone` AS t0_r18, `medics`.`professional_licence` AS t0_r19, `medics`.`customer_service_hours` AS t0_r20, `medics`.`confirmation_token` AS t0_r21, `medics`.`confirmed_at` AS t0_r22, `medics`.`confirmation_sent_at` AS t0_r23, `medics`.`failed_attempts` AS t0_r24, `medics`.`unlock_token` AS t0_r25, `medics`.`locked_at` AS t0_r26, `payment_methods`.`id` AS t1_r0, `payment_methods`.`premium` AS t1_r1, `payment_methods`.`cancel_at_period_end` AS t1_r2, `payment_methods`.`charge_date` AS t1_r3, `payment_methods`.`creation_date` AS t1_r4, `payment_methods`.`current_period_number` AS t1_r5, `payment_methods`.`period_end_date` AS t1_r6, `payment_methods`.`status` AS t1_r7, `payment_methods`.`trial_end_date` AS t1_r8, `payment_methods`.`openpay_subscription_id` AS t1_r9, `payment_methods`.`openpay_customer_id` AS t1_r10, `payment_methods`.`cancelled_on` AS t1_r11, `payment_methods`.`medic_id` AS t1_r12, `payment_methods`.`created_at` AS t1_r13, `payment_methods`.`updated_at` AS t1_r14 FROM `medics` LEFT OUTER JOIN `payment_methods` ON `payment_methods`.`medic_id` = `medics`.`id` WHERE (`payment_methods`.`period_end_date` IS NOT NULL)
  PaymentMethod Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `payment_methods`.* FROM `payment_methods`
       (0.1ms)  BEGIN

```
  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:15:13', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:19' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 1
   (11.9ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:15:13', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:19' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 2
   (2.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:15:13', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:19' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 3
   (2.6ms)  COMMIT
User medic1@mail.com update, Complete!

  PaymentMethod Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `payment_methods`.* FROM `payment_methods`
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:16:24', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:20' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 1
   (11.9ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:16:24', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:20' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 2
   (2.7ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:16:24', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:20' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 3
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
User medic2@mail.com update, Complete!

  PaymentMethod Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `payment_methods`.* FROM `payment_methods`
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:18:30', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:22' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 1
   (2.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:18:30', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:22' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 2
   (2.6ms)  COMMIT
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN

  SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `payment_methods` SET `creation_date` = '2018-06-15 19:18:30', `updated_at` = '2018-06-15 21:01:22' WHERE `payment_methods`.`id` = 3
   (2.6ms)  COMMIT
User medic4@mail.com update, Complete!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin haberme adentrado mayormente en la lógica de tu código, creo que deberías estar usando `user.payment_methods.update` en vez de `PaymentMethod.update`.
Este último actualiza todos los registros de la tabla `payment_methods` con los valores que le estás pasando en cada iteración. Yo "asumo" que deberías solo actualizar los métodos de pago que tenga el médico de la iteración actual y no toda la tabla.

Comment: Tienes razón ya lo resolví pasandole el id para cada objeto `PaymentMethod.where(id: @subscription_id, medic_id: @medic_id).update()`